# Check check box is check or not using onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to find whether the checkbox is checked or not in the onclick function.
How can i do this ?

**my code:**

```
if($checkdata==1)
        {
         $yescheck="checked";

        } else {
          $yescheck="";

        }

<input type="checkbox"  '<?php echo $yescheck; ?>' class="test" id="pick"/>

$(".transportcomment").click(function(){    

        if($(".test").is(":checked"))
        {       
        var pickupoption="1";
        }else{      
        var pickupoption="0";
        }
    console.log(pickupoption);
});

console always return 1.
```

Comment: where html tag which have class "transportcomment"??

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/esb3moxm/

Comment: Which version of jquery are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working , there is nothing wrong in your code

```js
$(".transportcomment").click(function() {
  if ($(".test").is(":checked")) {
    var pickupoption = "1";
  } else {
    var pickupoption = "0";
  }
  console.log(pickupoption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="test" id="pick" />
<button class="transportcomment">click</button>
```

May be if the page contains multiple check-box with class name `test` , at that case any of them is checked then `$(".test").is(":checked")` will return `true` . In that case use `id` instead of class.

Comment: the input tag and button is in foreach loop,what i do now?

Comment: if any of the input tag is checked it will log as `1`

Comment: to select a unique input tag use `$(".test").eq(0).is(":checked")` instead of `$(".test").is(":checked")`